# How to print raw logs to fluentd with Go rather than using a json map

Tags: go, logging, fluentd

I am using a golang function to print logs to fluentd. Fluent Post() method accepts only a map and not a string. I need a function to print raw text rather than forcing me to create a map.

Is that possible?

Below is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/fluent/fluent-logger-golang/fluent"
)

var Flogger *fluent.Fluent

func init() {
    initFluent()

}

func initFluent() {
    var err error
    Flogger, err = fluent.New(fluent.Config{FluentPort: 24224, FluentHost: "127.0.0.1"})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Could not connect to Fluent at %s Error : %v", os.Getenv("FLUENTHOST"), err)
    }
}

// DebugLog (msg string)  Logs the string to Fluent server
func DebugLog(msg string) {
    //Flogger.Post("debug.access", map[string]string{"data": msg})
    Flogger.EncodeAndPostData("debug.access", time.Now(), map[string]string{"data": msg}) // both methods give same result
}

func main() {
    msg := `{"mykey":"myval"}`
    fmt.Println(msg) //  prints {"mykey":"myval"}
    DebugLog(msg)    //  prints {"data":"{\"mykey\":\"myval\"}"}   with extra \

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function signatures as per the [Fluent GoDoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/fluent/fluent-logger-golang/fluent) as as follows:

```
func (f *Fluent) EncodeAndPostData(tag string, tm time.Time, message interface{}) error
```

```
func (f *Fluent) Post(tag string, message interface{}) error
```

Both functions accept the empty interface as the message parameter. All Go types satisfy the interface, so you can pass in anything that you'd like.

However, Fluentd is a *structured* logging library that primarily relies on `JSON` encoded data. Usually when using a third-party library, it serves well to use it the way it was intended.

> Fluentd tries to structure data as JSON as much as possible: this
>   allows Fluentd to unify all facets of processing log data: collecting,
>   filtering, buffering, and outputting logs across multiple sources and
>   destinations

Source: [Fluentd Website](https://www.fluentd.org/architecture)

Comment: I changed the fluentd  call to  
{
     Flogger.EncodeAndPostData("debug.access", time.Now(), msg) 
}
But I can see nothing in the fluentd log files

Comment: I can see errors in td-agent logs 
#0 [input_forward] unexpected error on reading data host="127.0.0.1" port=52474 error_class=ArgumentError error="record must be a Hash: String"
  2019-11-25 13:57:25 +0530 [error]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace

Comment: What datatype is `msg`?

Comment: Looking through the `fluentd` code, it seems like lower down the chain, even if you don't provide a `map` directly, the library attempts to convert the `msg` into some form of `json` or `key:value` pairs.

I re-iterate my previous point. You're using a `json` structured logging library, if you go against the grain you're likely to run into issues.